# Create dynamic stored procedure for all databases with specific table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to add the following stored procedure to all existing databases which contain the table `schichten`. All my approaches have failed so I'm looking for help here.

This is my approach:

```
IF object_id('tempdb.dbo.#database') is not null 
    drop TABLE #database
GO

CREATE TABLE #database(id INT identity primary key, name sysname)
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO #database(name)
    SELECT name 
    FROM sys.databases 
    WHERE source_database_id is null 
    ORDER BY name

SELECT * FROM #database

DECLARE @id INT, @cnt INT, @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @currentDb SYSNAME;

SELECT @id = 1, @cnt = max(id) FROM #database

WHILE @id <= @cnt
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT @currentDb = name 
        FROM #database 
        WHERE id = @id

        IF OBJECT_ID(@currentDb+'.dbo.schichten') IS NOT NULL
            CREATE PROCEDURE @currentDb.[dbo].[Ausw_Tabelle_Taxi_Pers_Jahr] 
                @ColumnName nvarchar(MAX), 
                @Selector nvarchar(MAX), 
                @Gesamtergebnis nvarchar(MAX)
            AS
            BEGIN
                SET NOCOUNT ON;

                DECLARE @sql1  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
                        @ASSelector nvarchar(MAX),
                        @IFPers nvarchar(MAX);

                IF @Selector = 'konz'
                BEGIN
                    SET @ASSelector = 'Taxi'
                    SET @IFPers=''
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @ASSelector = 'Personal'
                    SET @IFPers = '[name] AS Name,'
                END

                SET @sql1 = N';WITH temp AS (SELECT *
                        FROM (
   SELECT
          ISNULL((DATENAME(m,[datum])+ cast(datepart(yyyy,[datum]) as varchar(5))),0) AS MONTHYEAR,
          ISNULL(['+ @Selector +'],0) AS '+ @ASSelector +','+ @IFPers +'              
          ISNULL((ISNULL([umsum],0) +
                          ISNULL([sonst_0],0) +
                          ISNULL([sonst_7],0) +
                          ISNULL([sonst_16],0) +
                          ISNULL([sonst_z],0) -
                          ISNULL([ff],0)),0)        AS UMSATZSUMME 

   FROM [dbo].[schichten]

   ) AS SOURCE
  PIVOT (SUM([UMSATZSUMME]) FOR [MONTHYEAR] IN ('+ @ColumnName + N' )) AS UMSAETZE ) 
SELECT *, '+ @Gesamtergebnis +'  AS Gesamtergebnis FROM temp ORDER BY '+ @ASSelector +''

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

END

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

SET @id = @id + 1;

END

GO
```

I am hoping that there is someone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the `create procedure` separately, so if you wrap it up into a variable and use `exec sp_executesql` it should work.

```
IF object_id('tempdb.dbo.#database') is not null 
    drop TABLE #database
GO

CREATE TABLE #database(id INT identity primary key, name sysname)
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO #database(name)
    SELECT name 
    FROM sys.databases 
    WHERE source_database_id is null 
    ORDER BY name

SELECT * FROM #database

DECLARE @id INT, @cnt INT, @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @currentDb SYSNAME;

SELECT @id = 1, @cnt = max(id) FROM #database

WHILE @id <= @cnt
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT @currentDb = name 
        FROM #database 
        WHERE id = @id

        IF OBJECT_ID(@currentDb+'.dbo.schichten') IS NOT NULL
        begin
            set @sql = 'CREATE PROCEDURE '+@currentDb+'.[dbo].[Ausw_Tabelle_Taxi_Pers_Jahr] 
                @ColumnName nvarchar(MAX), 
                @Selector nvarchar(MAX), 
                @Gesamtergebnis nvarchar(MAX)
            AS
            BEGIN
                SET NOCOUNT ON;

                DECLARE @sql1  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
                        @ASSelector nvarchar(MAX),
                        @IFPers nvarchar(MAX);

                IF @Selector = ''konz''
                BEGIN
                    SET @ASSelector = ''Taxi''
                    SET @IFPers=''''
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @ASSelector = ''Personal''
                    SET @IFPers = ''[name] AS Name,''
                END

                SET @sql1 = N'';WITH temp AS (SELECT *
                        FROM (
   SELECT
          ISNULL((DATENAME(m,[datum])+ cast(datepart(yyyy,[datum]) as varchar(5))),0) AS MONTHYEAR,
          ISNULL([''+ @Selector +''],0) AS ''+ @ASSelector +'',''+ @IFPers +''              
          ISNULL((ISNULL([umsum],0) +
                          ISNULL([sonst_0],0) +
                          ISNULL([sonst_7],0) +
                          ISNULL([sonst_16],0) +
                          ISNULL([sonst_z],0) -
                          ISNULL([ff],0)),0)        AS UMSATZSUMME 

   FROM [dbo].[schichten]

   ) AS SOURCE
  PIVOT (SUM([UMSATZSUMME]) FOR [MONTHYEAR] IN (''+ @ColumnName + N'' )) AS UMSAETZE ) 
SELECT *, ''+ @Gesamtergebnis +''  AS Gesamtergebnis FROM temp ORDER BY ''+ @ASSelector +''''

EXEC sp_executesql @sql1

END'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

SET @id = @id + 1;

END

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a one time need as opposed to a nightly maintenance task, you can use a built-in stored procedure, sys.sp_MSforeachdb, to execute a statement in each database.  It is safe to use and has been discussed extensively on the web.  However, it is an undocumented feature and can be removed without notice by Microsoft so you don't want to depend on it for recurring tasks.

Create and validate your statement in one database, then use this stored procedure to execute it in all of the databases.  ? is the placeholder for the database name.

```
EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb @command1 = 
  'IF OBJECT_ID(''?.dbo.schichten'') IS NOT NULL
   AND OBJECT_id(''?.[dbo].[Ausw_Tabelle_Taxi_Pers_Jahr]'') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
CREATE PROCEDURE ?.[dbo].[Ausw_Tabelle_Taxi_Pers_Jahr] 
                @ColumnName nvarchar(MAX), 
                @Selector nvarchar(MAX), 
                @Gesamtergebnis nvarchar(MAX)
            AS
            BEGIN
                SET NOCOUNT ON;

                DECLARE @sql1  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
                        @ASSelector nvarchar(MAX),
                        @IFPers nvarchar(MAX);

                IF @Selector = ''konz''
                BEGIN
                    SET @ASSelector = ''Taxi''
                    SET @IFPers=''''
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @ASSelector = ''Personal''
                    SET @IFPers = ''[name] AS Name,''
                END

                SET @sql1 = N'';WITH temp AS (SELECT *
                        FROM (
   SELECT
          ISNULL((DATENAME(m,[datum])+ cast(datepart(yyyy,[datum]) as varchar(5))),0) AS MONTHYEAR,
          ISNULL([''+ @Selector +''],0) AS ''+ @ASSelector +'',''+ @IFPers +''              
          ISNULL((ISNULL([umsum],0) +
                          ISNULL([sonst_0],0) +
                          ISNULL([sonst_7],0) +
                          ISNULL([sonst_16],0) +
                          ISNULL([sonst_z],0) -
                          ISNULL([ff],0)),0)        AS UMSATZSUMME 

   FROM [dbo].[schichten]

   ) AS SOURCE
  PIVOT (SUM([UMSATZSUMME]) FOR [MONTHYEAR] IN (''+ @ColumnName + N'' )) AS UMSAETZE ) 
SELECT *, ''+ @Gesamtergebnis +''  AS Gesamtergebnis FROM temp ORDER BY ''+ @ASSelector +''''

EXEC sp_executesql @sql1

END
'
```